# Can Automapper map a paged list?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'd like to map a paged list of business objects to a paged list of view model objects using something like this:

```
var listViewModel = _mappingEngine.Map<IPagedList<RequestForQuote>, IPagedList<RequestForQuoteViewModel>>(requestForQuotes);
```

The paged list implementation is similar to Rob Conery's implementation here:
http://blog.wekeroad.com/2007/12/10/aspnet-mvc-pagedlistt/

How can you setup Automapper to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AutoMapper does not support this out of the box, as it doesn't know about any implementation of `IPagedList<>`.  You do however have a couple of options:

1. Write a custom `IObjectMapper`, using the existing Array/EnumerableMappers as a guide.  This is the way I would go personally.
2. Write a custom TypeConverter, using:

   ```
   Mapper
       .CreateMap<IPagedList<Foo>, IPagedList<Bar>>()
       .ConvertUsing<MyCustomTypeConverter>();
   ```

   and inside use `Mapper.Map` to map each element of the list.

Comment: Can someone provide a solid implementation of `PagedListTypeConverter`?

Comment: A working TypeConverter for Troy Goode's PagedList into a simple ViewModel can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470156/automapper-custom-type-converter-not-working/12538611#12538611

Answer (score 38):

Using jrummell's answer, I created an extension method that works with [Troy Goode's PagedList](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList).  It keeps you from having to put so much code everywhere...

```
    public static IPagedList<TDestination> ToMappedPagedList<TSource, TDestination>(this IPagedList<TSource> list)
    {
        IEnumerable<TDestination> sourceList = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TDestination>>(list);
        IPagedList<TDestination> pagedResult = new StaticPagedList<TDestination>(sourceList, list.GetMetaData());
        return pagedResult;

    }
```

Usage is:

```
var pagedDepartments = database.Departments.OrderBy(orderBy).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize).ToMappedPagedList<Department, DepartmentViewModel>();
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of writing.

Comment: How would this work when you have fields you want AutoMapper to ignore?

Comment: And if you get any errors after trying this, make sure to read this: http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-creating-mappings/   It has some really good information you should read before using AutoMapper

Comment: A really elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using [Troy Goode's PageList](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList), there's a [`StaticPagedList`](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList/StaticPagedList.cs) class that can help you map.

```
// get your original paged list
IPagedList<Foo> pagedFoos = _repository.GetFoos(pageNumber, pageSize);
// map to IEnumerable
IEnumerable<Bar> bars = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Bar>>(pagedFoos);
// create an instance of StaticPagedList with the mapped IEnumerable and original IPagedList metadata
IPagedList<Bar> pagedBars = new StaticPagedList<Bar>(bars, pagedFoos.GetMetaData());
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to return a serializable version of `IPagedList<>` with AutoMapper version 6.0.2 that supports the `IMapper` interface for ASP.NET Web API. So, if the question was how do I support the following:

```
//Mapping from an enumerable of "foo" to a different enumerable of "bar"...
var listViewModel = _mappingEngine.Map<IPagedList<RequestForQuote>, PagedViewModel<RequestForQuoteViewModel>>(requestForQuotes);
```

Then one could do this:

**Define `PagedViewModel<T>`**
*Source: [AutoMapper Custom Type Converter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12470156/642287)*

```
public class PagedViewModel<T>
{
    public int FirstItemOnPage { get; set; }
    public bool HasNextPage { get; set; }
    public bool HasPreviousPage { get; set; }
    public bool IsFirstPage { get; set; }
    public bool IsLastPage { get; set; }
    public int LastItemOnPage { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int TotalItemCount { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Subset { get; set; }
}
```

**Write open generic converter from `IPagedList<T>` to `PagedViewModel<T>`**
*Source: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Open-Generics*

```
public class Converter<TSource, TDestination> : ITypeConverter<IPagedList<TSource>, PagedViewModel<TDestination>>
{
    public PagedViewModel<TDestination> Convert(IPagedList<TSource> source, PagedViewModel<TDestination> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return new PagedViewModel<TDestination>()
        {
            FirstItemOnPage = source.FirstItemOnPage,
            HasNextPage = source.HasNextPage,
            HasPreviousPage = source.HasPreviousPage,
            IsFirstPage = source.IsFirstPage,
            IsLastPage = source.IsLastPage,
            LastItemOnPage = source.LastItemOnPage,
            PageCount = source.PageCount,
            PageNumber = source.PageNumber,
            PageSize = source.PageSize,
            TotalItemCount = source.TotalItemCount,
            Subset = context.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TDestination>>(source) //User mapper to go from "foo" to "bar"
        };
    }
}
```

**Configure mapper**

```
new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<RequestForQuote, RequestForQuoteViewModel>();//Define each object you need to map
        cfg.CreateMap(typeof(IPagedList<>), typeof(PagedViewModel<>)).ConvertUsing(typeof(Converter<,>)); //Define open generic mapping
    });
```

Comment: This worked beautifully for me! Allows me to convert to any `Type` I have

Answer (score 2):

It is easy with Automapper .net core 8.1.1

You just need to add type map to your mapperProfile and mapping the  object inside pagedList

```
CreateMap(typeof(IPagedList<>), typeof(IPagedList<>));
CreateMap<RequestForQuote, RequestForQuoteViewModel>().ReverseMap();
```

It also can be and abstract class like PagedList. It is not related with class/ınterface type

And you can use it directly in mapper.Map - Initialize mapper from IMapper in the class constructor

```
RequestForQuote result
_mapper.Map<IPagedList<RequestForQuoteViewModel>>(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

AutoMapper automatically handles conversions between several types of lists and arrays:
http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays

It doesn't appear to automatically convert custom types of lists inherited from IList, but a work around could be:

```
    var pagedListOfRequestForQuote = new PagedList<RequestForQuoteViewModel>(
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<RequestForQuote>, List<RequestForQuoteViewModel>>(((List<RequestForQuote>)requestForQuotes),
        page ?? 1,
        pageSize
```

Comment: This method loses the `StartRecordIndex`, `EndRecordIndex`, `TotalItemCount` and `TotalPageCount` properties.

Answer (score 1):

I created a little wrapper around AutoMapper to map `PagedList<DomainModel>` to `PagedList<ViewModel>`.

```
public class MappingService : IMappingService
{
    public static Func<object, Type, Type, object> AutoMap = (a, b, c) =>
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "The Mapping function must be set on the MappingService class");
    };

    public PagedList<TDestinationElement> MapToViewModelPagedList<TSourceElement, TDestinationElement>(PagedList<TSourceElement> model)
    {
        var mappedList = MapPagedListElements<TSourceElement, TDestinationElement>(model);
        var index = model.PagerInfo.PageIndex;
        var pageSize = model.PagerInfo.PageSize;
        var totalCount = model.PagerInfo.TotalCount;

        return new PagedList<TDestinationElement>(mappedList, index, pageSize, totalCount);
    }

    public object Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource model)
    {
        return AutoMap(model, typeof(TSource), typeof(TDestination));
    }

    public object Map(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (source is IPagedList)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "Parameter source of type IPagedList is not supported. Please use MapToViewModelPagedList instead");
        }

        if (source is IEnumerable)
        {
            IEnumerable<object> input = ((IEnumerable)source).OfType<object>();
            Array a = Array.CreateInstance(destinationType.GetElementType(), input.Count());

            int index = 0;
            foreach (object data in input)
            {
                a.SetValue(AutoMap(data, data.GetType(), destinationType.GetElementType()), index);
                index++;
            }
            return a;
        }

        return AutoMap(source, sourceType, destinationType);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TDestinationElement> MapPagedListElements<TSourceElement, TDestinationElement>(IEnumerable<TSourceElement> model)
    {
        return model.Select(element => AutoMap(element, typeof(TSourceElement), typeof(TDestinationElement))).OfType<TDestinationElement>();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
PagedList<Article> pagedlist = repository.GetPagedList(page, pageSize);
mappingService.MapToViewModelPagedList<Article, ArticleViewModel>(pagedList);
```

It is important that you would have to use the **element** types!

If you have any question or suggestions, please feel free to comment :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using X.PageList then you can simply use this code:

```
PagedList<exampleDTO> result = new PagedList<exampleDTO>(item, _mapper.Map<List<exampleDTO>>(item.ToList()));
```

The PageList lets you to create new PageList with modified items.

[more information](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList/blob/master/src/X.PagedList/PagedList.cs#:%7E:text=public%20PagedList(IPagedList%20pagedList%2C%20IEnumerable%3CT%3E%20superset))